# Is it possible to use IUserType as an Id in Fluent Hibernate mapping?

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have a IUserType defined class and I want to use it as an Id of a table.  When using Native generator I get an exception

```
InnerException: System.InvalidOperationException
    Message=Identity type must be integral (int, long, uint, ulong)
    Source=FluentNHibernate
```

My next step is to investigate custom generators but I wanted to verify that its possible to use user types as Ids.

So, can it be done?

Comment: is the Id Property an integral type? if no then you have to write your own

Comment: Did you solve this question? I have a similar question but using NHibernate Mapping By Code.